# NAICS code or name in Schema.org

Tags: seo, schema.org

I am using schema.org to describe stocks on my website. Schema.org says I should use the NAICS code: http://schema.org/Organization. But I am not sure if the NAICS numerical code is better or the NAICS text name. E.g:

Which one should I use:

Code: 111199

Name: Barley farming, field and seed production

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a specific programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NAICS in schema.org is derived from appropriate property in [GoodRelations](http://purl.org/goodrelations/) vocabulary.
And in GoodRelations owl ontology [file](http://www.heppnetz.de/ontologies/goodrelations/v1.owl) you can find

```
  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#hasNAICS">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int"/>
    <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">has NAICS (0..*)</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:domain>
      <owl:Class>
        <owl:unionOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
          <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#BusinessEntity"/>
          <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://schema.org/Organization"/>
        </owl:unionOf>
      </owl:Class>
    </rdfs:domain>
    <rdfs:comment xml:lang="en">The North American Industry Classification System (NAICS) code for a particular gr:BusinessEntity.
See http://www.census.gov/eos/www/naics/ for more details.

Note: While NAICS codes are sometimes misused for classifying products or services, they are designed and suited only for classifying business establishments.</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:isDefinedBy rdf:resource="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1"/>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
```

You're interested in this paricular line

`<rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#int"/>`

So even though type of the property in schema.org is Text it is better to use numerical code.

Comment: I found this article useful for developing an SEO friendly framework. For that reason, I think this question is valid for a code related forum such as stackoverflow because it is directly related to developing code. Without HTML, this question does not exist.